# Java Variable changing to 0 (Android)

Tags: java, android

I have a long data type to store the system current time - `playTime`.  I print the value of it at one point and it shows the correct number, and when I print it again later it shows 0.

Here is the code

```
System.out.println(playTime);

if (!updatedScore){

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println(playTime);
        //Code to print value to textview


     }});
}
```

updatedScore is always false in this case

On my last run it printed:

```
1973562817652
0
```

Comment: How is playtime updated?

Comment: I guess `playTime` is a class member. When do you assign a value to `playTime`? AFAIK `post` does not necessarily execute the `Runnable` instantly.

Comment: You are right about the runnable not being executed instantly, thats why, my next line outside the runnable set it back to 0. Thank you! If you want to put your answer down below I'll mark it as correct for you

Answer (score 0):

define *playTime* as `final long playTime`

```
boolean updatedScore = false;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
final long playTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(playTime);
if (!updatedScore){
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(playTime);               
        }});
}
```

if it doesn´t work, look for other value assignation to *playTime* in your code, is impossible that *playTime* could change to "0" with just this code.